# How to set QVideoWidget to fullscreen and have a volume slider in the fullscreen widget?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm working on a simple video looping app and would like to know if there is a way to add a volume slider control to the fullscreen mode of *QVideoWidget*.

I want the app to show a small *QVideoWidget* at startup. Then after double clicking the video widget, I want the video to be shown at fullscreen with an additional volume slider.

Currently I have a code based on the *QMultimedia* example which looks like this:

In *videowidget.h*

```
#ifndef VIDEOWIDGET_H
#define VIDEOWIDGET_H

#include <QVideoWidget>

class VideoWidget : public QVideoWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    VideoWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);

protected:
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event);
    void mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
};

#endif // VIDEOWIDGET_H
```

the  *videowidget.cpp*

```
void VideoWidget::mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    setFullScreen(!isFullScreen());
    event->accept();
}
```

One solution I could think of is to create a base widget to draw another videowidget and a slider and load it in the double click event, but I have difficulty implementing it. I don't have a clue how to transfer the current playing states of the media player to the new video widget.

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmultimedia-multimediawidgets-player-example.html

Comment: @Jiu, I have already studied the code in that example. Basically I think I know how to change volume with a slider and how to set the QVideoWidget to fullscreen. What I mean in my question is How to add the slider in the fullscreen widget..

Comment: Are you trying to make the slider overlay on the `VideoWidget`? What is the layout you want?

Comment: @Jiu, I would accept any layout as long as it gets the job done. I edited my question btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QVideoWidget>
#include <QSlider>
#include <QMediaPlayer>
#include <QFileDialog>

/**
 * @brief The VideoWidget class
 *
 * VideoWidget contains QSlider & QVideoWidget
 */
class VideoWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QVideoWidget* videoWidget;
    QSlider* slider;
public:
    VideoWidget() :
        videoWidget(new QVideoWidget(this)),
        slider(new QSlider(Qt::Horizontal, this))
    {
        slider->hide();
        slider->move(10, 10); // Put slider where you want.
        slider->setRange(0, 100);

        const QMediaContent meida(QFileDialog::getOpenFileUrl());
        QMediaPlayer* player = new QMediaPlayer(this);
        player->setVideoOutput(videoWidget);
        player->setMedia(meida);
        player->play();

        slider->setValue(player->volume());
        connect(slider, &QSlider::valueChanged, player, &QMediaPlayer::setVolume);
    }
    virtual ~VideoWidget() {}
protected:
    /**
     * @brief changeEvent
     * @param event
     *
     * Listen to window state change event,
     * and show the slider only when the state is WindowFullScreen.
     */
    void changeEvent(QEvent* event) {
        if(event->type() == QEvent::WindowStateChange)
            slider->setVisible(windowState() == Qt::WindowFullScreen);
        QWidget::changeEvent(event);
    }

    /**
     * @brief resizeEvent
     * @param event
     * 
     * Make videoWidget fill the parent widget.
     */
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* event) {
        videoWidget->resize(size());
        event->accept();
    }

    void mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent *event) {
        if(!isFullScreen())
            showFullScreen();
        else
            showNormal();
        event->accept();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    VideoWidget w;
    w.resize(500, 400);
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: Wow, this code shows profound understanding of QT! I've played with it and changed the mouseDoubleClickEvent

Comment: I'm also trying to hide the QSlider at startup and when widget is normal  but I think it is way beyond my understanding. Is it possible to hide Qslider during normal widget size, then show during fullscreen?

Comment: @Lowen I update the code, If any part not clear, please leave a comment...

Comment: Hey @Jiu, with regards to the slider, I asked another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52199122/why-is-qslider-not-updating-its-position-immediately-in-its-ui

Comment: @Lowen you could modify the code to your current version, and copy to the new question...make everybody understand what was happen...

Comment: I asked a different question for the same project here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52365710/how-to-set-the-video-back-to-main-widget-after-transferring-it-to-another-dialog.