# Why QResizeEvent & QWidget::size gives different when fullscreen?

Tags: qt, qwidget

The question is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/52151020/3308570.
(contains an example to reproduce the problem)

I'm trying to get the widget size when it shows fullscreen. At first, I took the size from `QResizeEvent::size`. But the size only works correctly once. Like:

1. show fullscreen
2. QResizeEvent::size ⇒ `1920x1080`
3. show normal
4. QResizeEvent::size ⇒ `500x400`
5. show fullscreen
6. QResizeEvent::size ⇒ `516x439`

Then I changed to using `QWidget::size` in `QResizeEvent`, it gives the correct result `1920x1080` always when fullscreen.

Is this a bug, or I did something wrong?

Env: Qt 5.10.1 Mingw32 Win10

**Update:**

I found the problem because the `videoWidget` show incorrect size. Then I check the size by debugging.

Thanks @Scheff ,I replaced the `resizeEvent` function part to observe the problem:

```
ushort i = 0;
void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* event) {
    i++;
    const QSize sizeEventOld = event->oldSize();
    const QSize sizeEvent = event->size();
    const QSize sizeWidgetBefore = size();
    const QSize sizeWidgetAfter = size();
    qDebug() << "Widget::resizeEvent():" << i;
    qDebug() << "QResizeEvent::oldSize  :" << sizeEventOld;
    qDebug() << "QResizeEvent::size     :" << sizeEvent;
    qDebug() << "Widget::size() (before):" << sizeWidgetBefore;
    qDebug() << "Widget::size() (after) :" << sizeWidgetAfter;
    videoWidget->resize(size());
    event->accept();
}
```

**Mingw32, MSVC2013 Output:**

```
Widget::resizeEvent(): 1 // The window initilized
QResizeEvent::oldSize  : QSize(-1, -1)
QResizeEvent::size     : QSize(500, 400)
Widget::size() (before): QSize(500, 400)
Widget::size() (after) : QSize(500, 400)
Widget::resizeEvent(): 2 // Double click, show fullscreen.
QResizeEvent::oldSize  : QSize(500, 400)
QResizeEvent::size     : QSize(1920, 1080)
Widget::size() (before): QSize(1920, 1080)
Widget::size() (after) : QSize(1920, 1080)
Widget::resizeEvent(): 3 // Double click, show normal.
QResizeEvent::oldSize  : QSize(1920, 1080)
QResizeEvent::size     : QSize(500, 400)
Widget::size() (before): QSize(500, 400)
Widget::size() (after) : QSize(500, 400)
Widget::resizeEvent(): 4 // Double click, show fullscreen(2nd time)
QResizeEvent::oldSize  : QSize(500, 400)
QResizeEvent::size     : QSize(516, 439)
Widget::size() (before): QSize(1920, 1080)
Widget::size() (after) : QSize(1920, 1080)
Widget::resizeEvent(): 5 // Double click, show normal(2nd time)
QResizeEvent::oldSize  : QSize(1920, 1080)
QResizeEvent::size     : QSize(500, 400)
Widget::size() (before): QSize(500, 400)
Widget::size() (after) : QSize(500, 400)
```

Comment: @Scheff I add info of my work environment, the example code in the first link.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the part of _contains a example to reproduce the problem_.

Comment: Did you try this _without_ `event->accept();` in `VideoWidget::resizeEvent()`?

Comment: @Scheff I tried just now but got the same.

Comment: Finally, I was able to reproduce your problem. Notably, it worked correctly in cygwin but failed when I compiled in VS2013 instead. (The XWindow manage of cygwin may play a role. Actually, I switched to VS as I couldn't get working neither `showFullScreen()` nor `showMaximized()` and suspected the cygwin XWin concerning this.)

Answer (score 2):

The Qt doc. states clearly that [`QResizeEvent::size()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qresizeevent.html#size)

> Returns the new size of the widget. This is the same as [QWidget::size()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#size-prop).

So, I believe the observed/reported behavior is a bug which might be limited to the MS Windows specific part of Qt.

I made the following MCVE to reproduce.

`testQResize.cc`:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

class Widget: public QWidget {
  private:
    unsigned _i; // event counter
    QPushButton _qBtn;
  public:
    Widget(QWidget *pQParent = nullptr);

  protected:
    virtual void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *pQEvent);
  private:
    void toggleFullScreen();
};

Widget::Widget(QWidget *pQParent):
  QWidget(pQParent),
  _i(0), _qBtn("Click to toggle fullscreen mode", this)
{
  connect(&_qBtn, &QPushButton::clicked,
    [this](bool) { toggleFullScreen(); });
}

void Widget::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *pQEvent)
{
  ++_i;
  const QSize sizeEventOld = pQEvent->oldSize();
  const QSize sizeEvent = pQEvent->size();
  const QSize sizeWidget = size();
  _qBtn.resize(pQEvent->size());
  //QWidget::resizeEvent(pQEvent);
  // report
  qDebug() << "Widget::resizeEvent():" << _i;
  qDebug() << "pQEvent->oldSize():" << sizeEventOld;
  qDebug() << "pQEvent->size()   :" << sizeEvent;
  qDebug() << "this->size()      :" << sizeWidget;
  qDebug() << "this->_qBtn.size():" << _qBtn.size();
}

void Widget::toggleFullScreen()
{
  if (!isFullScreen()) showFullScreen();
  else showNormal();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  Widget win;
  win.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

`testQResize.pro`:

```
SOURCES = testQResize.cc

QT = widgets
```

First, I compiled and tested on [**cygwin64**](http://www.cygwin.org) on Windows 10 but I was not able to reproduce the issue. (Compiling on cygwin means in my case, this Qt depends on X11.)

Btw. I was a bit annoyed as the `showFullScreen()` hadn't any effect. I suspected the cygwin XWin manager (a very special thing which acts as intermediator to embed X windows in Windows. – However, I know it has certain weaknesses.)

So, I compiled and tested on VS2013 (platform 64 bit):

```
Version: 5.9.2
Widget::resizeEvent(): 1
pQEvent->oldSize(): QSize(-1, -1)
pQEvent->size()   : QSize(100, 30)
this->size()      : QSize(100, 30)
this->_qBtn.size(): QSize(100, 30)
Widget::resizeEvent(): 2
pQEvent->oldSize(): QSize(640, 480)
pQEvent->size()   : QSize(640, 480)
this->size()      : QSize(120, 30)
this->_qBtn.size(): QSize(640, 480)
Widget::resizeEvent(): 3
pQEvent->oldSize(): QSize(120, 30)
pQEvent->size()   : QSize(2560, 1440)
this->size()      : QSize(2560, 1440)
this->_qBtn.size(): QSize(2560, 1440)
Widget::resizeEvent(): 4
pQEvent->oldSize(): QSize(2560, 1440)
pQEvent->size()   : QSize(120, 30)
this->size()      : QSize(120, 30)
this->_qBtn.size(): QSize(120, 30)
Widget::resizeEvent(): 5
pQEvent->oldSize(): QSize(120, 30)
pQEvent->size()   : QSize(136, 69)
this->size()      : QSize(2560, 1440)
this->_qBtn.size(): QSize(136, 69)
Widget::resizeEvent(): 6
pQEvent->oldSize(): QSize(2560, 1440)
pQEvent->size()   : QSize(120, 30)
this->size()      : QSize(120, 30)
this->_qBtn.size(): QSize(120, 30)
```

(2560x1440 was full size in my case.)

The issue manifests after `Widget::resizeEvent(): 5`.

I have no idea why this happens but it seems to be limited to the Qt MS Windows specific code.

However, the OP presented already a work-around which appears very reasonable to me: not to rely on `QResizeEvent::size` but to use the `QWidget::size` property instead.