# How to set the video back to Main Widget after transferring it to another DialogWindow using mouse event handler?

Tags: c++, qt

I am making a video player using Qt and C++ with the following requirements:

1. Upon starting the app, the video should play in loop.
2. When you click the video, another dialog/window should open containing the video and a volume slider. The video should continue playing in this new dialog/window and not go back to the beginning.
3. When you click again the video from the new dialog/window, the dialog/window should close and the video should continue playing in the main.

From studying examples and reading documentations, I was able to come up with a program which can do requirements 1 & 2 but not 3.

To briefly describe the lengthy code below, basically it's composed of 4 classes as follows:

- mainwidget (inheriting QWidget) : This is the main widget. It contains VideoWidget which is a video container
- VideoWidget (inheriting QVideoWidget) : the video container. This is where I constructed the video player and playlist to easily call `QMultimediaPlayer::setVideoOutput` in the reimplemented `QWidget::mousePressEvent` handler. This is also where I created the seconddialog object.
- seconddialog (inheriting QDialog) : This is another window containing slider and SecondVideoWidget.
- SecondVideoWidget (Inheriting QVideoWidget) : `QWidget::mousePressEvent` handler was also reimplemented but `QMultimediaPlayer::setVideoOutput(VideoWidget*)` cannot be directly called here. It would solve my problem if I could do something like that in the `mousePressEvent` function.

Apologies for the lengthy example but I tried trimming this down by not including header files and deconstuctor.

mainwidget.cpp

```
#include "mainwidget.h"
#include <QtWidgets>

mainwidget::mainwidget(QWidget *parent)
: QWidget(parent)
{
 videoWidget = new VideoWidget(); // the video container
 videoWidget->setFixedSize(500, 300);
 //videoWidget->setGeometry(100,100,300,400);
 videoWidget->show();

 QBoxLayout *displayLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
 displayLayout->addWidget(videoWidget, 2);


 QBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
 layout->addLayout(displayLayout);

 setLayout(layout);
}
```

videowidget.cpp

```
#include "videowidget.h"
#include "seconddialog.h"
#include "mainwidget.h"
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QEvent>
#include <QMouseEvent>

QMediaPlaylist* VideoWidget::playlist = new QMediaPlaylist();
QMediaPlayer* VideoWidget::player = new QMediaPlayer();

bool VideoWidget::clicktoggle = false;

VideoWidget::VideoWidget()
: videoWidget(new QVideoWidget(this))
{    
const QMediaContent medium(QFileDialog::getOpenFileUrl());
playlist->addMedia(medium);
playlist->setPlaybackMode(QMediaPlaylist::Loop);

player->setPlaylist(playlist);
player->play();
player->setVideoOutput(videoWidget);
}

void VideoWidget::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* event)
{
videoWidget->resize(size());
event->accept();
}

void VideoWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
   if(clicktoggle)
   {
    player->setVideoOutput(videoWidget);
    clicktoggle = false;
   }
   else
   {
    seconddialog fpv;
    fpv.setModal(true);
    fpv.exec();
}
event->accept();

}
```

seconddialog.cpp

```
#include "seconddialog.h"
#include <QtWidgets>
#include "videowidget.h"

seconddialog::seconddialog(QDialog *parent) : QDialog(parent)
{
slider = new QSlider(Qt::Horizontal,this);
fvw = new SecondVideoWidget();

this->setGeometry(100,100,500,500);
slider->setValue(VideoWidget::player->volume());

VideoWidget::player->setVideoOutput(fvw);

QBoxLayout *controlLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
controlLayout->addWidget(fvw);
controlLayout->addWidget(slider);

setLayout(controlLayout);

connect(slider, &QSlider::valueChanged, VideoWidget::player, &QMediaPlayer::setVolume);

}
```

secondvideowidget.cpp

```
#include "secondvideowidget.h"
#include "videowidget.h"

#include <QEvent>
#include <QMouseEvent>

SecondVideoWidget::SecondVideoWidget() : SecondvideoWidget(new QVideoWidget(this))
{
QPalette p = palette();
p.setColor(QPalette::Window, Qt::black);
setPalette(p);

setAttribute(Qt::WA_OpaquePaintEvent);
}

void fullVideoWidget::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* event)
{
fullvideoWidget->resize(size());
event->accept();
}

void fullVideoWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
this->close();
VideoWidget::clicktoggle = true;
event->accept();
}
```

Comment: Please, focus on one problem. Do not post your whole project. Instead describe the (single) issue you have and provide just enough code to be able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Sorry, But I'm very new to Qt and C++ and I'm not knowledgeable enough in making a simple code that would reproduce my problem. But I'll try trimming the code down. Basically this code can transfer the videoplayer to another video container inside another dialog. Now, i want it to go back after clicking and that's what I wanted to ask..

Comment: What's `fullpromovid`

Comment: @Jiu : it's seconddialog, sorry!